# Is it possible to redirect STDOUT to a Logger?

Tags: ruby, logging, child-process

I have a class [`ChildProcess`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/childprocess/2.0.0/ChildProcess) from [`childprocess`](https://github.com/enkessler/childprocess) gem. It expects me to configure logging this way:

```
process = ChildProcess.build(...)
process.io.stdout = Tempfile.new("/tmp/file.txt")
```

However, I don't have a file to log to. Instead, I have an instance of [`Logger`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) class. I need to find a way to create a wrapper around `Logger` in order to make it look like an "writeable stream" (I'm not sure what it means in this case, though). Do you know a gem to help me do this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert, but couldn't you use the `IO.pipe` [as shown here](https://github.com/enkessler/childprocess#output-to-pipe) and pass that to the Logger?

Comment: I've not used the Logger, but it looks like you send messages to an instance [using functions](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-How+to+log+a+message). So instead of the `print` function show in the [link in my example](https://github.com/enkessler/childprocess#output-to-pipe), can't you use the `logger.info` (or whatever you need) with the logger instance that you have?